# symfony2 multilanguage message error with form validator through yml

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3, xml-twig, xliff

I have a yml file for the user form validation (a form like many others):

```
# src/User/RegBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
    User\RegBundle\Entity\User:
      properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: ~
          - Length:
              min: 2
              max: 255
              minMessage: error_min_message
              maxMessage: error_max_message
```

The form is rendered into the *twig* like below

```
//...
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form_row(form.surname) }}
{{ form_row(form.gender) }}
{{ form_row(form.email) }}
//...
```

My symfony2 website has a multilanguage structure and there are the *messages.mylang.xliff* file for the words translation.
All works right.
My question is whether there's a way to insert the "error_min_message" into the *messages.mylang.xliff* or there are others ways to translate that messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation strings go to `validators.LANG.FORMAT` instead of `messages.LANG.FORMAT`. Don't forget to clear the cache after you add a new translation file.

Comment: It would appear to work but ther's a way to pass the "variable"?
This is my _validators.LANG.xliff_:
   `<trans-unit id="1_name_min_length" datatype="plaintext">
Like in this sample, i refer to the  `{{lang}}` variable

Comment: Everything works exactly as `messages.LANG.FORMAT` do. Just a different file.

Comment: I tried.
This is the snapshot into the _xliff_ file:
`<target xml:lang="it">Il nome deve avere minimo {{limit}} caratteri</target>` 
It prints {{limit}} instead of 2 for example.

Comment: My stupid error was that i haven't put the space between the brackets and the word limit. ^_^
`{{ limit }}` this is correct instead of this `{{limit}}`